# Help demystify the Navy PFA equations.

Tags: matrices

I need help finding an equation that the Navy's Physical Readiness Program Office (PRIMS) keeps unpublished for some unexplainable reason and will not share after numorous requests.  Anyways, luckily, I have access to a calculator where I can input two variables ( weight, calories burnt) and it returns the equivalent run time. There are two fitness events which require this machine to run-time equation, those are stationary bike and ellipticals.  The elliptical equation was simple to recreate in javascript because I found a PDF explaining the conversion.  This is shown below, however, the conversion for the stationary bike is what I can't find.

The equation to convert elliptical calories burnt into a run-time goes like this:

1. Conduct a 12-min ET bout.
2. Obtain the machine calorie report, while correcting for machine bias:
   a. Add 0 kcal for bouts on the Lifefitness 9500 HR.
   b. Add 20 kcal for bouts on Nautilus Model E9 16.
   c. Add 7 kcal for bouts on Precor Model EFX 556.
3. Divide the calorie report from Step 2 by 12 to get energy production rate in kcal/min.
4. Multiply the test subject’s weight in pounds by 1.09 to determine the total energy
   required to run 1.5 mi.
5. Divide the result of Step 4 by the result of Step 3 to obtain the raw run time estimate in a decimal format.
6. Multiply the decimal portion of Step 5 by 60 to convert it to seconds. The result is the
   raw run time estimate expressed as min:sec.
7. Obtain the run time equivalent for the ET bout by adding 1:08 min for a male test
   subject or 2:15 for a female test subject.
8. Use the run test standards in the PRT instruction to convert the run time equivalent to a PRT score.

The above shows an expanded version of the equation: Raw Run Time Estimate = (13.08*Weight)/Machine Calorie Report     , plus 68 (1:08,mm:ss) or  135 (2:15,mm:ss) to correct for gender bias.

The above was taken from http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a462116.pdf

The equation to convert statinary bike calories burnt into a run-time goes like this:
?
?
?
?
?

This is where I am stuck.

In the case anyone is wondering what the purpose for this conversion is, it's two part: 1) curiosity, and 2) the last part of a IOS/Android/Windows phonegap application that I am making available to Sailors for free.

Thanks, I'm not the greatest a math, I can produce tables of the produced run time, weight, and calorie varibles if necessary.

Comment: I'm not asking anyone to solve this for me though I wouldn't complain, if someone could get me on the right path that would be helpful.

Comment: If I were attempting to solve this problem, I would create tables of runtime with corresponding weight/calorie variables.  Then, I would use some interpolation/curve fitting method to find a best-fit polynomial, and see if there's a pattern in common...  (Just an idea.)

Comment: Thank you anorton, I will be looking into your suggestion shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for females: (6.296+4.087*(weight/calories)+1.77)
for males: (6.296+4.087*(weight/calories))

Answer (score 1):

If you have tables with $m$ columns, $n$ rows, and you have a column whose value you are trying to match for general inputs, you can use regression techniques. The easiest  would be [linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression), which will give you the best fit straight line to the data. Note that if the formula they use is not linear it will do a poor job. You will want to generate the fit using a set of data, and then test it against a different set of data. If a linear model does not work try fitting the data with the lowest order polynomial you can. Excel has tools that will do this automatically.

Comment: Also note that the function the Navy uses is of two variables.  So, a typical linear regression fit might not be enough--some strategic pattern-matching/guesswork may be needed. ;)

Comment: Well, starting to build the tables - so far I can at least say that the step 7 for elliptical is the same as for the bike conversion, so at least the gender bias correction is exactly the same.

Comment: thanks for your comments I tried up voting but I don't have the necessary reputation.

Answer (score 1):

With a little research I actually found that the fomula is:

Males: 6.296+(4.087*[Weight in lb]))/Calories)

Females: 6.296+(4.087*[Weight in lb]))/Calories) + 1.77

I have not yet profed the female with parenthies, but male actually comes out wrong if you try deviding the Weight by calories first.

Comment: What's different from the accepted answer posted almost three months ago?

Answer (score 1):

If you log into PRIMS and click on the "help" tab, there is a bike/elliptical calculator that will convert the calories you burned into your run time. There is also a calculator that will determine your overall score based on the numbers you enter (as goals). In case anyway is looking at this and needs to know where to find a calculator.